# How to override a CollectionChanged event in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using VS2010 - WPF - C#

I have a listview that takes its items from a source using this instruction :

```
this.listView1.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(getTicker());
```

the problem is that every time the source gets updated, my listview doesn't get updated ??

I know I have to do something with the `OnCollectionChanged` event but I don't know how to do it

Please help me with that . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(getTicker());`

Assuming that `getTicker()` returns a list of items you can do

```
this.listView1.ItemsSource = getTicker();
```

If you want to make sure that your listview updates when the source collection changes then you have to use a collection which implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, for example `ObservableCollection` does that. However you have to make sure that your update your collection on the UI thread.

**Update**: Here is how you can use `ObservableCollection`:

```
var TickerData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
this.listView1.ItemsSource = TickerData;
```

Then you can add/remove items to/from `TickerData` and the UI will update itself automatically because `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which exposes a `CollectionChanged` event handler which the listview subscribes to.

I think you might want to have a look at [some tutorials on WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_1.aspx).

Comment: actually the getTicker() function returns a list of items

Comment: I want to do something like overriding the CollectionChanged event so that everytime the collection changes my listview gets updates dynamically

Comment: Override it where? If you bind your listview to a collection which fires the collection changed events then you are done.

Comment: I know I'm asking too many silly questions , but how can I do that I mean will the collection get updated by itself ? or do I have to do something in order to make it update itself ?

Answer (score 1):

What does the getTicker method does? If each call can return a new collection, maybe you are **replacing the collection** instead of adding/removing elements to it. I've seen it several times...

Make sure that when you have new items to add (or a whole new collection of items):
 1. Clear the collection (the one returned in getTicker) to remove all items
 2. Add all the new items to the collection

If you really don't need CollectionviewSource, simply bind an ObservableCollection...